# Associate the right input text data with its adjacent span content

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Here is a part of my HTML code:

```
<div id="customers" data-bind="foreach: employees">
  <p> <span data-bind="text:name"></span> <input  type="text"/>
  </p>
</div>
```

`employees` is an **observable array** created with knockout.js whose every element is an object with two properties; one of them is `name`. Imagine the array has, for example, 100 elements. That what I want is to write some data inside any of the 100 created input texts and update the corresponding row in the database which must be found through the adjacent **name** which in fact is a primary key in the corresponding database table. In which way may I find the right names associated with the right input boxes as to update the right rows?

Comment: Please show your model code to see what you've attempted.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your javascript looks like but you need to create a viewmodel and apply those bindings to knockout. But here is a simple [fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/L18j6j50/1/) with what I think you were trying to build. To build other properties that the foreach binding can see just add them to the object literals that are being created for the array in the fillData method in the fiddle.